# Using Python, how can I resize an image to fit an excel cell?

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, python-imaging-library, openpyxl

I've created a `tkinter` GUI tool that let's the user browse and upload an image and import it into an Excel sheet. The Excel sheet has a set row and column size so all images being imported would need to fit into that set cell size.

I tried doing this with some sample images, I resized them (while keeping their same aspect ratio) and imported them successfully.

```py
def run():
    global rowappend
    
    numbers = number()
    size = 5

    img = Image.open(image_file_path).convert('RGB')
    width, height = img.size
    img = img.resize((width//size, height//size))
    filenamevar = f'Kin image {numbers}.jpg'
    img.save(filenamevar)
    img2 = os.path.abspath(filenamevar)

    img = Image2(str(img2))

    global rowappend2

    img3 = Image.open(image_file_path2).convert('RGB')
    width, height = img3.size
    img3 = img3.resize((width//size, height//size))
    filenamevar2 = f'Kin image {numbers + 1}.jpg'
    img3.save(filenamevar2)
    img4 = os.path.abspath(filenamevar2)

    img3 = Image2(str(img4))

    wb.active = wb[radioselection.get()]
    ws = wb.active
    ws.column_dimensions['F'].width = 15
    ws.column_dimensions['E'].width = 20
    ws.column_dimensions['D'].width = 32
    ws.column_dimensions['C'].width = 32
    ws.column_dimensions['B'].width = 10
    ws.column_dimensions['A'].width = 10
    rowappend = int(ws.max_row + 1)
    ws.row_dimensions[rowappend].height = 230

    ws[f'A{rowappend}'] = bodypart_var.get()
    ws[f'B{rowappend}'] = exercise_var.get()
    ws.add_image(img, f'C{rowappend}')
    ws.add_image(img3, f'D{rowappend}')
    ws[f'E{rowappend}'] = instructions_var.get()
    ws[f'F{rowappend}'] = setsandreps_var.get()

    confirmation = tk.Label(root, text="Ready to be imported!", bd=1, bg='SeaGreen1', 
    justify="right")
    confirmation.grid(row=18, column=0)
```

But my problem is with resizing the images to fit the cell. I currently have images to reduce to 1/5th of their size, but every image uploaded will have different dimensions and won't fit the excel cell the same way.

Is there a way to grab the excel row and column size and resize the image so it fits in that set size?

Comment: why not save image as `numpy` array & revert back while accessing?Which will reduce half of your code.

Comment: How will that get the image to fit into the cell? @Bhargav